# What/Who writes changeset in liquibase change logs?

Tags: liquibase, changeset

It might be super obvious but no one bothered clarifying what or who is actually creating/writing the changesets for liquibase. I read more than a dozen articles related to changesets in liquibase and while I now understand how it works I still wonder if these changesets are generated somewhere by Liquibase ? Or are users supposed to write them by hand ?

And do we agree that the CHANGELOGTABLE, is populated from doing a liquibase update by reading the already existing changesets ? Not the other way around ?
And do we also agree that liquibase doesn't track schema changes, it just computes the desired state of a DB from the changesets ?

Thanks

Edit: I asked many questions, but ultimately I'm just looking for an answer to the title and somehow understand properly how liquibase works.

Comment: *You* write the changeset, to tell Liquibase what changes you want it to make to your databases. Liquibase updates the relevant table in each database it's run on so it knows which changes it's applied and can work out which still need to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write the changeset.  And since you can write changesets in [sql](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/sql-format.html), its just you writing the database scripts your application needs.

Yes, the [DATABASECHANGELOG](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/databasechangelog-table.html?Highlight=databasechange) table is the audit log that gets written after a liquibase update that shows what changesets got executed.

I would recommend taking the fundamentals course provided for free at [Liquibase University](https://learn.liquibase.com/) that covers these very basic concepts.  Without it, it will be much harder to be successful using Liquibase.  My experience: You can pretty much finish the course in one sitting or maybe an hour each day for a few days.